# Xbox 360 Memory Stick Failing: Copy?

Tags: xbox-360

The memory stick I use in my Xbox 360 is generally working but sometimes it fails to read (or write?)... I would like to replace it.

Can I just clone the memory stick using my Mac?

Comment: I would plug 2 memory sticks into your Xbox 360 and go to the system settings and into memory/storage and move the items over. The file system is not a normal one so it won't appear to be readable on your mac. As for a simple clone, no idea if that would work.

Comment: it certainly seems that cloning it on the system (or even better pushing it to your cloud save if you have xbox live gold) would be the easiest thing to do, does that not work for you?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen seems like copying the bytes on Mac didn't work. Will try using the Xbox 360 copying

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen if you want to make that an answer I could mark it as accepted, please

Comment: Dumb question, can you copy these files to the Xbox 360 HDD then back to the USB stick afterwards, or is this one of the models with only 0-4GB internal memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to obtain another memory stick (a normal USB stick should do).

Then plug both into the same Xbox and use the storage function on the console to move items from the bad stick to the new stick, hopefully salvaging as much as possible.

The disks are formatted with a special file system as soon as you opt to use them with your Xbox 360 so you can't really see the files if you plug the memory stick into a Windows or OS X machine.

Comment: If you do it via PC, the memory cards have to be the same(exactly the same size).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the command `dd` for that, which is available on all unix operating systems. it makes an exact copy of the stick.

See [this answer on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46253/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-a-disk-between-two-macs) for details, here is an excerpt though:

- Run `diskutil` to find the path of your USB drive
- Run dd to clone the drive:
  `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0 of=/dev/disk2 bs=128m conv=noerror,sync`

Please note that the devices used here are purely as example, you have to figure the device of your usb stick yourself via `diskutil`

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as accepted answer once I have "proven" it empirically (soon, need to acquire the new flash drive and do the work)

Comment: what's wrong with using Disk Utility? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46272

dd showed the to-be-copied resource as busy.

Comment: And disk utility shows an i/o error... hmmmm

Comment: `dd: /dev/disk2: Resource busy`

Comment: unmounting partitions per http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=384730

Comment: And... it worked! Except that Xbox thinks the new drive -- 16GB just like the one it was copying -- is blank. So there's some kind of copy protection going on. 

Thanks for your help!